# How do I extend a knockout viewmodel when using the knockout viewmodel plugin?

Tags: json, knockout.js, formatting, knockout-viewmodel-plugin

I'm using the **knockout.viewmodel** plugin (http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/) to generate my **viewModels** on the fly from **JSON** returned via **WebAPI**.
I'm having an issue extending the **viewModel** though.
Here's a sample of my test script:

JSON:

```
{"Employees":
    [
     {"FirstName":"James",
      "LastName":"Bond",
      "Addresses":[{"StreetNumber":"MI6","StreetName":"Undisclosed"},
                   {"StreetNumber":"SAS","StreetName":"Undisclosed"}]},
     {"FirstName":"Jason",
      "LastName":"Bourne",
      "Addresses":[{"StreetNumber":"CIA","StreetName":"Undisclosed"},
                   {"StreetNumber":"NSA","StreetName":"Undisclosed"}]}
    ]
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="POC">
    <div id="test"></div>
    <table>           
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table style="color:blue">                            
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Addresses">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: StreetNumber"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: StreetName"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input width="150" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input width="150" data-bind="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: addEmployee ">Add Agent</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:58191/api/employees", function (jsonModel) {

var options = {
    extend: {
        "{root}.Employees[i]": function (employee) {
            employee.addEmployee = function () {
                alert("add");
            }
        }
    }
}

var kovmmappingVM = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(jsonModel, options);    
ko.applyBindings(kovmmappingVM, document.getElementById("POC"));
});
```

The **JSON** is processed and bound properly, but the extended function doesn't get wired up.
I don't get any exceptions; the alert just doesn't fire.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your extension on `{root}.Employees[i]` instead of `{root}.Employees`. Thus the function is added to each `Employees` but your markup binds to the root as it is outside the `foreach`.

Replace with this:

```
var options = {
    extend: {
        "{root}.Employees": function (employees) {
            employees.addEmployee = function () {
                alert("add");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR

put your button inside the `foreach`

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  I discovered that as well.  Works like a charm now :)

Comment: Any recommended best practices for implementing the "addEmployee" function?  Seems straightforward; i plan to call the push function from the Employees collection in the viewModel.

Comment: @user3699387 Seems like the way to go :)

Comment: How do I reference the current viewModel for adding a record to the parent collection?  Any ideas...this is my test code, but it's not valid:

Comment: @user3699387 Can you post this as a new question?